# Vuetify Table - rendering column value based on a condition

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

[image]

I have a vuetify table and one of the columns is `url`. I need to add logic to either display URL or URL Group name. I can tell that based on the property of my **rules** array. If my rules[i].urlGroup != '' then I know

I have tried to add

```
<template v-slot:item.url="{ index, item }">
    {{ displayURLInfo(index) }}
</template>


displayURLInfo(index) {

    if (this.rules[index].urlGroup != '') {
        // console.log('this.rules[index].urlGroup', this.rules[index].urlGroup) // here printed perfectly on console.
        return this.rules[index].urlGroup
    } else {
        return this.url
    }
}
```

I was inside the first if condition, it consoles log perfectly, but it didn't render to the UI.

My rules array structure look like this. It's only has 5 properties

[image]

## What did I do wrong?

Comment: what is the first picture showing? what should it look like? `this.rules[index].urlGroup` looks to be an empty string - should you be returning `this.rules[index].url` if `this.rules[index].urlGroup` is empty ... perhaps?

Comment: looks like it should be `urlGroup` instead of `userGroup`

Comment: @RohìtJíndal I corrected the spelling ....  they should be `urlGroup` all codes updated. But that is not the main issue why it kept showing empty   :(

Comment: @Bravo If `urlGroup != ''` show it. Else, show `url`

Comment: as i said ... *should you be returning `this.rules[index].url` if `this.rules[index].urlGroup` is empty ... perhaps?* -exactly what the answer you accepted shows - so, not sure why you're uncorrecting me

Comment: @Bravo so sorry, I missed read your comment, you're 100% correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do below correction in the displayURLInfo() method **:**

- Use `urlGroup` instead of `userGroup`.
- Instead of `return this.url` it should be `return this.rules[index].url`

**Working Demo :**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data () {
    return {
      headers: [
        { text: "Priority", value: 'priority' },
      { text: "Name", value: 'name' },
      { text: "URL", value: 'url' },
    ],
      rules: [{
      priority: 1,
      name: "Alpha",
      url: 'https://example.com',
      urlGroup: ''
    }, {
      priority: 2,
      name: "Beta",
      url: 'https://example.com',
      urlGroup: 'userGroup2'
    }],
    }
  },
  methods: {
    displayURLInfo(index) {
      if (this.rules[index].urlGroup != '') {
         return      this.rules[index].urlGroup
      } else {
        return this.rules[index].url
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify@2.6.4/dist/vuetify.min.css"/>
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="rules"
    >
      <template v-slot:item.url="{ index, item }">
    {{ displayURLInfo(index) }}
</template>
    </v-data-table>
  </v-app>
</div>
```